# Main menu navigation links and new pages

Tags: menus, pages, links

Sorry i'm pretty new on wp, i would like to add new menu links and site pages, to the main top menu bar.

I'm using a third parties template, and i see the top.php file which contains the top menu looks like:

```
<div id='mainmenu-container'>
      <div id='mainmenu'>
        <?php $nav_menu_params=array(
          'depth'=>0,
          'theme_location'=>'main-menu',
          'menu_class'=>'menus menu-primary',
          'fallback_cb'=>'block_main_menu'
        );
        wp_nav_menu($nav_menu_params); ?>
      </div>
```

how does  i edit this code or how can i enter anyway new links and new web site pages from backend side?

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates can all have unique code, and your template may or may not support [Custom Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen). I would find out if you can add custom menus through your Appearance > Menus tab in the admin area. If you can't, all new pages you add from the Pages tab will most likely end up in that main menu by default.

If you **can** add custom menus, then you should look up the function you are referencing [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) to get a good understanding of how to place your code.

Also check to see if you have the option to set the menu which will be your main menu in the Menus tab.

Comment: Right. Being new to WP, you will learn a lot about your theme. Some theme designers only add 1 menu. You can add your own extra menus but you'll need to follow instructions from someone telling you how to do it. It is sad when themes come with only 1 menu when the user needs more but the beauty of it all is you can add as many as you like if you know how.